# Angular1.5 custom directive sets ng-dirty after click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have built some custom directives for inputs.
I want to use them and show an error message if the entered value isn't valid. 
Consequently every ng-message is shown on the condition "form.input.$dirty".

If i click on inputs which uses my custom directive it becomes dirty. But I think it shouldn't. Inputs which use required or/and max just doesn't show the message and aren't dirty. So I suggest that the error is in my directive.

one custom directive:

```
{
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    ngModel: '=',
    countryCode: '<'
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

    middlewareConfigService.getCountries().then(function (response) {
      scope.countries = response.data;
      ctrl.$validate()
    })


    var isValidBic = function isValidBic(value) {
      if (!value)
        return true;

      value = value.toUpperCase();
      if (!(value.length === 8 || value.length === 11)) {
        return false;
      }

      if (scope.countryCode) {
        return value.substring(4, 6) === scope.countryCode
      }

      if (scope.countries) {
        return scope.countries.filter(function (country) {
            return country.key === value.substring(4, 6)
          }).length > 0;
      }
      return true;
    };
    ctrl.$validators.ngBic = function (modelValue) {
      return isValidBic(modelValue);
    };
  }
}
```

Is something missing? Is the directive the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you get the list of countries what is the ctrl.$validate() doing? I'm not seeing that come up in AngularJS documentation. I think it might have somethign to do with you asynchronously getting a list of countries. There's an async example in Angular's documentation. Maybe check that out

Comment: It starts the validation cycle new. I need it when the input is prefilled. Otherwise the input starts the validation cycle without knowing countries so a validation isn't usefull.

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez I just removed ctrl.$validate(), but the problem appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the official documentation:

[ngModel directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#css-classes)

> ng-dirty: the control has been interacted with

[ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController$dirty)

> $dirty True if user has already interacted with the control.

Therefore it is not your directive at fault here, but your slight misunderstanding of the conception of "dirty".

Comment: But if I use a normal input with required this way, it is touched but not dirty. I think that interacted mean that the input value has changed.

Comment: You're right, just checked for myself and made sure the controls don't become dirty upon simply focusing-blurring.

Comment: I went ahead and made a [code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/t9no8wj7/14/) to check whether I am missing something here, but no luck - ng-dirty does not appear to me unless I change the model. Can you show me the HTML of your input?

Comment: Oh, it isn't the custom directive. I also use a third part directive, which causes this problem, thank you for your help